Complex-valued functions on a finite group as linear combinations
In a lecture on group representations, the professor set $G$ to be a finite group, and $\mathbb{C}[G]$ as the set of all complex-valued functions on $G$.  Then he said that, supposing that $\varphi\in\mathbb{C}[G]$, and that, $\forall g\in G, \varphi:g\mapsto a_g\in\mathbb{C}$, we can write $$\varphi = \sum_{g\in G} a_g \; g .$$
Now, this all came at the end of the class period.  The professor was clearly rushing through this material, as he seemed pressed for time, frequently looking at the clock on the wall.  He certainly went too quickly for me.  I don't yet see what justifies identifying the complex-valued function $\varphi$ with the linear combination shown above.  Can someone fill in why this identification is reasonable?

In this linear combination $\sum_{g\in G} a_g \; g$, the final $g$ is a shorthand notation (very usual in this context) for the function
$$\delta_g:G\to\Bbb C,\quad h\mapsto\begin{cases}1&\text{if }h=g\\0&\text{else.}\end{cases}$$
A clearer formulation would be:
$$\varphi = \sum_{g\in G}a_g\;\delta_g .$$
In other words, $(\delta_g)_{g\in\ G}$ is a basis of the complex vector space $\Bbb C[G]$, and $(a_g)_{g\in G}=(\varphi(g))_{g\in G}$ is the coordinates of $\varphi$ in this basis. Note that the same holds when the group $G$ is infinite, the group algebra $\Bbb C[G]$ being then defined as the $\Bbb C$-algebra of all complex-valued function on $G$ with finite support.

Thank you for this explanation.  Also, sorry about the "formal" in the original version of my question.  That was my own word choice.  I gather from your answer that it was not a good one.  Be that as it may, I have now removed it.

So have I, then. This word is often used when pretending to define $\Bbb C[G]$ informally as "the set of all formal (finite) linear combinations of elements of $G$", but the definition given by your professor is less hazy.
